# What the relation between Immediate Alert Service and Proximity profile in BLE(Bluetooth 4.0)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to iOS development, and study about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) for IOS

I have found the information like [Proximity profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.proximity.xml) and it use the `Service` of `Immediate Alert`.
The description of **`Proximity profile`** is like the following:

```
When a device moves away from a peer device so that the connection is dropped or the path loss increases above a preset level, causing an immediate alert.
```

**The condition-A:Using `Proximity profile`**

The **`Proximity profile`** use **`immediate alert Service`** to start alert when a device moves away from a peer device.

**The condition-B:Without using `Proximity profile`**

I can get the `RSSI`from the `BLE device` and use the **`immediate alert Service`** to start alert when the `RSSI` is out of range which I have setting(For example: -75dbm).

**`The question is like the following:`**

What the different between **`condition-A`** and **`condition-B`** ??

Is the `Profile` just a theory ? and the `Service` is the real application ?

Answer (score 0):

The profile defines the semantics of the service, while the service just contains a formal description of characteristics it contains, and has an assigned UUID.